# How to read/write different types with an ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, io, server, inputstream, outputstream

I want to be able to use my Object Input/Output Stream to send booleans, UTF and Objects between a server and client. Independently I have no trouble sending a String or boolean but when I have two threads in while loops, one doing .readBoolean and the other .readUTF errors got thrown. I could see why that way wouldn't work but I can't figure out the correct method.

How can I send different types over the stream? Are multiple ports needed or can I do it over one with the same stream?

Comment: Why are you sending two Objects over a stream? Send one object with two values... Eg. Make a new object named anything and send anything using ojbectstream and read object by ((anything)receivedobject).getString(); and ((anything))receivedobject).getBoolean(); both methods specific to anything class

Comment: @YaWang
I kind of have it setup like this now before i figure out how to do what I want, I am just sending strings with identifying prefixes before it. If I can't find the proper way I may do something like your idea though

Answer (score 0):

You might notice that the `readXYZ` methods in `ObjectInputStream` correspond to the `writeXYZ` methods in `ObjectOutputStream`.

Each pair of methods reads or writes a particular format. If you write something with `writeBoolean` (which writes a single byte) you must read it with `readBoolean`. If you write something with `writeObject` (which writes a serialized object) you must read it with `readObject`. Trying to interpret a serialized `Boolean` object as a single-byte boolean will not work.

Comment: @TheAwkwardChild Then you have to send something to say whether the next thing is a boolean or a string. Or you could use `readObject`/`writeObject` which handle the type automatically (and then use `instanceof`)

Answer (score 0):

> when I have two threads in while loops, one doing .readBoolean and the other .readUTF errors got thrown. I could see why that way wouldn't work but I can't figure out the correct method.

There isn't a correct method. Two threads reading from the same socket is never going to work.

> How can I send different types over the stream?

You're doing it. Your problem isn't the types, it is the concurrency.

> Are multiple ports needed

Probably, but you haven't told us enough about your requirement to be sure.

> or can I do it over one with the same stream?

You *are* doing it over one stream, but you're running into concurrency problems. The content of the stmrea itself isn't well-defined, and nor is the order in which the two threads will read. You can't do this. Rethink, redesign, re-implement.